# Operation in data frame, Python, sorting date

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

```
taxa_cdi = pd.read_csv("/Users/matheuscosta/Desktop/AventGard/Fundo de dados/dados CDI .csv",delimiter=";",encoding='cp1252')

index_taxa_cdi = pd.DataFrame(taxa_cdi,columns=["Data","Média"]) 


index_taxa_cdi=index_taxa_cdi.pivot_table(index="Data",values="Média",aggfunc='sum')

index_taxa_cdi.sort_index(axis=0, level=None, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last', sort_remaining=True, by=None)
```

My problem is that the program is sorting by the day of the date, but I want to sort, first, by the year of the date, and after it the month, then the day

[image]

Comment: your column is type datetime or date?

Comment: `index_taxa_cdi['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(index_taxa_cdi['Data'])` before `pivot_table`.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked. Is there a way to remove the time that appears after that line code